# Keck versus Webb: discrepancies in the redshift measurements of the galaxy GN-z11 (the most distant galaxy discovered with the Hubble Space Telescope)

Tags: cosmology, astronomy, galaxies, redshift, telescopes

Two years ago Nature Astronomy published a paper based on measurements from the Keck Telescope stating that the redshift of the galaxy GN-z11 (discovered by Hubble) is:

$$ z=10.957 \pm 0.001 $$

Source: [***Evidence for GN-z11 as a luminous galaxy at redshift 10.957***](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41550-020-01275-y)

Yesterday the pre-print of the paper [***JADES NIRSpec Spectroscopy of GN-z11: Lyman-α emission and possible enhanced nitrogen abundance in a z=10.60 luminous galaxy***](https://arxiv.org/abs/2302.07256) was published in arxiv. This article has been submitted for publication to the journal "*Astronomy & Astrophysics*"

It states that the latest James Webb Space Telescope measurements indicate that the redshift of this galaxy is:

$$ z=10.6034 \pm 0.0013 $$

The error bars of these measurements do not overlap. Who must be measuring wrong, Keck or JWST?

Best regards

Comment: Isn't it true that "redshifts of galaxies" are actually redshifts of objects within the galaxies (gas clouds, etc.) and that different objects can have slightly different values? Maybe neither value is wrong.